# Html.Actionlink shows my model data

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm passing my model to actionlink using that

```
@Html.ActionLink("download", "action", "controller", Model, null)
```

But it generates html

```
<a href="/secure/action/controller?PrivateNo=3123123&amp;LastName=lastname ..... >download</a>
```

So if user will change something it will affect to passed parameter and it will serious vulnerability. How can I avoid that?

---

as asked in comments i provide more details about controller.

```
public ActionResult List(MyModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            bla bla bla

            MyModel myModel = new MyModel()
            {
                PrivateNo = PrivateNumber,
                FirstName = FirstName,
                ...
            };


            ...
        }

        ...
    }
```

and in view I have

```
@Html.ActionLink("download", "GenerateDoc", "controller", Model, null)
```

and it goes to action which generates pdf

```
    public ActionResult GenerateDoc(MyModel pdfModel)
    {
        string pdfData = FillTemplate(pdfModel);
        byte[] source = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pdfData);
        byte[] resultDoc = Convert(source, "Template.xml");

        return File(resultDoc, "application/pdf", Server.UrlEncode("test.pdf"));
    }
```

Comment: Why are you passing a model in a link?

Comment: @StephenMuecke else how can I call action with parameter? I need that to generate and download pdf from another action.
`public ActionResult GenerateDoc(Model pdfModel)`

Comment: The normal practice is to send the ID of the model (and depending on your model this may fail anyway - you may exceed the query string limit and throw an exception, or it any of the properties of the model are complex objects or collection, binding will fail)

Comment: This issue because you are passing your `Model` in  your `ActionLink`. If need to do this please share your controller code I will provide you the better option to do that. Thanks

Comment: If you only want to remove query string from 'ActionLink' , You can use form approach. But when you post the from that will show all the parameter in url. If you don't want to show parameter in URL then you have to add hidden field for your `Property` on your view..
I can share both codes if you want to follow these process. Thank you :)

Comment: @SunilKumar can you show me second? thanks

Comment: @George, That's nonsense (you cannot download a file in a POST method). Just do it the right way and send only the ID of the model - `@Html.ActionLink("download", "GenerateDoc", "controller", new { id = Model.ID }, null)`, and get the model in the `GenerateDoc()` method

Comment: Your code shows that when you renders this page, your model is already saved in db, if so then why don't you just pass the id?

Comment: @NaveedYousaf because it's not saved in db

Answer (score -1):

Please achieve this by using `form` approach in your code Please refer below code:
On `.cshtml/View` page you have to put `hidden` fields (if you don't want to show these properties on page, it can also work for `TextBoxes`) for your `Properties` like below:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index","Home",FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.PrivateNo) 
    @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.FirstName) 
    @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.LastName) 
<input type="submit" name="Submit" title="Submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

and on `Controller` you can get these values by following code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

after that you will get all the values on `controller` :

See below :

[image: Controller]

[image: View Page]

as you can see we have got the `values` from view to `controller` and no `parameter` is shown in `URL`.

Hope it helps you..:)

Thanks.

Happy coding :)

Comment: OP is wanting to go to a method that returns a FileResult and this will not work (not to mention that a malicious user can just as easily change the value of the hidden inputs as they can the url in a link)

Comment: Hello sir I think OP don't want to show parameter information into URL. 
My post only regarding that.

Comment: It pointless to post an answer which has nothing to do with OP's problem.